# update label text through MainPage Helper class

Tags: c#, label, maui, winui-3, winui

To simplify my scenario, I have a label and a button in a MAUI application.
And I want to update the label text through mainpagehelper class instead of mainpage class.

**MainPage.xaml**:

```html
<Button
    x:Name="OrganizeBtn"
    Text="Organize"
    IsEnabled="False"
    Clicked="OnOrganizeClicked"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

<Label x:Name="completionMsg"
    FontSize="32"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```java
private void OnOrganizeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        completionMsg.Text = "";
        MainPageHelper mh = new FileManager();
        int fileCount = mh.OrganizeFiles(folderPath.Text);
        completionMsg.Text = "Moved " + fileCount + " files!";
    }

public void UpdateCompletionText(string text)
    {
        completionMsg.Text = "Moving " + text + "...";
    }
```

**MainPageHelper.cs**:

```java
public int OrganizeFiles(string folderToOrganize)
        {
            foreach (string folder in listOfFolders)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderToOrganize + "\\" + folder);
                MainPage mp = new MainPage();
                mp.UpdateCompletionText(currentFile);  <--- want to update the label here
            }
        }
```

Here, when I debugged by keeping the breakpoint, the call is going to the `UpdateCompletionText` function in MainPage. But the text is not updating.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Your helper class is creating a **new instance** of MainPage instead of referencing the **existing instance** that is being displayed to the user.  Even if you fix this the UI is going to update too quickly to be seen by the user

Comment: How to get the existing instance instead of creating the new instance?

Comment: pass a reference when you create the helper class.  But this is still poor design.  A better approach would be to have the helper raise an event every time it processes a file, then the UI can subscribe to that event and update itself.  Regardless, as I mentioned earlier, neither approach is likely to produce a good UX result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the helper is to be able to update the page, it needs a reference to the page instance.

You could inject it with one:

**MainPageHelper.cs:**

```
private MainPage _mainPage;

//constructor:
public MainPageHelper(MainPage mainPage)
{
    _mainPage = mainPage;
}

public int OrganizeFiles(string folderToOrganize)
{
    foreach (string folder in listOfFolders)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderToOrganize + "\\" + folder);
        _mainPage.UpdateCompletionText(currentFile);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
private void OnOrganizeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    completionMsg.Text = "";
    MainPageHelper mh = new MainPageHelper(this);
    int fileCount = mh.OrganizeFiles(folderPath.Text);
    completionMsg.Text = "Moved " + fileCount + " files!";
}
```